# GroupBy() in EF Core 3.1 seems to be broken

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Trying to migrate from EF6 to EFCore 3.1 is a very frustrating process due to a number of [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes) they introduced. However, `GroupBy()` is promised to be supported in 3.1, right?

```cs
IQueryable<Condition> myquery = dbctx.Conditions.Where(e => e.Rule.Namespace == "test");

var d = await myquery.GroupBy(e => e.RuleId).SelectMany(e => e).ToArrayAsync();
```

fails with

> System.InvalidOperationException : Processing of the LINQ expression
> 'x => x' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may
> indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed
> information.

Seeing that even simple queries EF6 was translating without issues do not work in EF Core is just unbelievable :(
Is there a workaround for this sort of queries?

Comment: My honest assessment of EF Core over the years is that EF Core 3.1 was *not* a production ready tool. EF Core 5 was *mostly* production ready, and EF Core 6 is the first production ready version.  That hasn't stopped numerous teams from shoe-horning EF Core 3.1 into thousands of production systems. :)

Comment: @StevePy, because it is last version which works with .NET Framework. I really cannot understand Microsoft's politic in such case.

Comment: If you are sticking with. Net 4.8 then why switch from EF6? EF Core 3.1 is marginally faster in a few cases, but weighed against the lack of feature support it's honestly not worth it. It isn't an upgrade to EF6. The only push for EF Core pre-Core 6 would be cross-platform but that's arguably Beta-level suitability.

Comment: @StevePy, we're upgrading a huge multi-repo solution and simply cannot jump straight to .NET6, so this is an unfortunate intermediate step for us :(

Comment: I mean EF6, (6.4.4) the last .Net Framework targeted EF build. not EF Core 6.,..

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to surprise, EF Core 3.1 is less feature supported version of EF Core  and has a lot of limitations especially for grouping. These limitations are closely coupled with SQL limitations.

For example, your query

```cs
var d = await myquery.GroupBy(e => e.RuleId)
   .SelectMany(e => e)
   .ToArrayAsync();
```

Means that you want to group records and return grouping details. This query has no analogues in SQL world.

Solution is simple - do grouping on the client side:

```cs
var d = (await myquery.ToListAsync())
   .GroupBy(e => e.RuleId)
   .SelectMany(e => e)
   .ToArray();
```

For query

```cs
var d = await myquery.GroupBy(e => e.RuleId).CountAsync();
```

Looks like again about EF Core 3.1 limitation (EF Core 6+ should handle this)
As workaround you can replace with the following:

```cs
var d = await myquery
   .Select(e => e.RuleId)
   .Distinct()
   .CountAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks. The second case can even be simplified to `myquery.Select(e => true).CountAsync()` but I don't think I can live with client side evaluation in the first case - the existing query is much more complex and grabs too many rows :(

Comment: So update question with real query. I think I now everything about LINQ and EF Core limitations.